# How can I write a minimal egress NetworkPolicy for a workload that talks to the Kubernetes API server on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to write a minimal egress NetworkPolicy for a workload running on GKE that needs to talk to the apiserver.

Is there any other way of doing this other than creating the cluster, getting the address of the LB fronting the apiserver(s) and then templating this into a NetworkPolicy? Is there any way of picking an external apiserver IP beforehand that can remain static over cluster recreates? Or, as a last resort, getting some list of CIDRs that GKE will always choose the apiserver LB IP from?

Answer (score -3):

best choice is to use calico by enabling network policy on GKE, check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/network-policy-support-for-kubernetes-with-calico), and here are [some tips](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/tutorials/advanced-policy) to Allow or Denie ingress or engress

Comment: This does not explain how the policy can actually be written (e.g. making it dynamic based on the apiserver address)

Comment: No you can't in GKE, as you said the only option is to wait until you get the External IP of LB apiserver (master node) then you setup your Network policy, GKE is a managed cluster, but you can if you deploy and run kubernetes on GCE instance